# Show Sum of query results based on main form in text box

Tags: ms-access

I have created a basic database in Access 2013 for project management.
Therein I have set up a main table called `Project-properties` which holds Project ID as a unique identifier and other fields for project properties. This table is linked via a 1:n connection to another table called `Invoices` which holds all invoices corresponding to a unique project.

I then went on to create a form based on the `Project-properties`. On this form I want to display a text field showing the sum of all invoices corresponding to the selected project.

Imagine I have 10 invoices spread across 4 projects, with $10k each resulting in a total of $100k. What I want show in the form is only the sum of the invoices corresponding to, let's say project ID 01. In the `Invoices` table, only 3 quotations correspond to this project ID with $10k each, so the aforementioned text field should show $30k.

I have tried with `=Dsum('InvoiceSum';'Invoice')` but I only get the sum of all projects $100k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DSum` (and associated domain lookup functions) have a third argument that allows you to specify a filter.

If the project field is a string, then you would use something like:

```
=DSum("InvoiceSum","Invoice","ProjectID='ID01'")
```

If you wish to have the filter dependent on a variable, then this would become:

```
Dim strProject As String
strProject="ID01"
=DSum("InvoiceSum","Invoice","ProjectID='" & strProject & "'")
```

If this is a control on a form, and the Project ID is numeric, then you would use this as the control source of a text box, as long as ProjectID is included in the Recordsource of the form:

```
=DSum("InvoiceSum","Invoice","ProjectID=" & ProjectID)
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer! I maybe should've clarified, that the Project ID is based on an increasing integer for every added project. First Project -> Project ID = 1 and so on. If I were to set a filter as you suggested, in this case "1", wouldn't I always get the sum for the project 1, no matter which entry I'd jump to?

Comment: Use the last expression as _ControlSource_ for your textbox displaying the value: `=DSum("InvoiceSum";"Invoice";"[Project ID]=" & [Project ID] & "")`

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for that suggestion. Unfortunately, if I was using the table "invoice" I still only got the sum of all invoices. I tried with a query using Project ID and InvoiceSum as criteria resulting in `=Dsum("InvoiceSum";"QueryInvoice";"[Project ID]=" & [Project ID] & "")  ` this finally worked in giving me the correct sum when selecting different projects. Massive thanks! I was struggling with this for days now (even if it might be a trivial issue..) Has someone an idea why the table query did not work?

Comment: After making this work with "invoiceSum" I tried to repat it with a different field i added to the Query called "Actual Invoice" and i used the same Code: `=Dsum("Actual Invoice;"QueryInvoice";"[Project ID]=" & [Project ID] & "")`  but this suddenly doesnt display the correct values! The only difference I can see is, that the field "Actual Invoice" is not calculated in the original table but put in manually. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Try square brackets around `Actual Invoice` - `=Dsum("[Actual Invoice];"QueryInvoice";"[Project ID]=" & [Project ID] & "")`.

Comment: i love this communty! this worked thanks @Applecore . Could you maybe explain why this works with square brackets now?

Comment: Any time that you have spaces (or special characters) in SQL (which includes using Domain Aggregate functions), you need to use square brackets to ensure that the field or table name is interpreted correctly.